# How do I get the coordinates of an image same on all devices?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I tried out all the possible solutions but they are not working for me .
I have an ImageView with an image. I am able to get the coordinates on touch of the image, but when I click on same point of the Image in different resolution device the the coordinates are different.
I want that the coordinates must be the same on all devices , So that i am able to get the exact point where the image is touched .

My current code is:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    final TextView coordinateText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.coordinateText);
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            String text = " x = " + motionEvent.getX() + " and y = " + motionEvent.getY();
           // Log.d("Tag", "X,Y : " + motionEvent.getX() + "," + motionEvent.getY());
            coordinateText.setText(text);

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

activity_main.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="saleskit.orbitsys.com.damagemarkingdemo.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/coordinateText"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/superb_dm_left_v01"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: use `ImageView`'s inverted `Matrix`, get the original `Matrix` by calling `ImageView#getImageMatrix()` method

Comment: Thanks for your response could you show me an Example .

Comment: i dont have any

Comment: Could someone show me the implementation ?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Tried a lot , But does't work fine . May be it will be help full if someone provide any link.

Comment: then post what you `"Tried a lot"`

Comment: Please tell why X,Y is not the same for all devices. How come?

Comment: `How do I get the coordinates of an image same in all devices?`. Pretty bad description of your problem. Images have no coordinates to begin with.

Comment: Hey @greenapps just suppose we have an Image of a car And I marked point of the Image I want that the coordinate of the point where I marked is same in all devices .

Comment: Please tell. Those X,Y values. What are they exactly? (Tip: they have noting to do with your image/bitmap.). When X,Y == 0,0 ?

Comment: `Please tell why X,Y is not the same for all devices. How come? `. You did not answer. Any reason why not?

Comment: @greenapps lets assume the image is a little tiny green robot and OP wants to click on its left eye and then he knows that "left eye" on the original bitmap is a circle with center (100, 150) and radius 10, then he wants to get that 100, 150 no matter how big his screen is

Comment: @pskink. No need to clarify. I know exactly what OP wants, what happens, the problem and solution.  Just here to let OP realize what his problem actually is. OP should start answering my questions. Then he will realize what happens.

Comment: @greenapps if he ignored `ImageView#getImageMatrix` and the rest i doubt he will answer your questions: most likely he just wants a "copy/paste" code

Comment: @pskink Indeed OP should experiment with those matrixes to.  And just answer all questions.